# Summarize Pandas dataframe to Half-Hourly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like the `issue` dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

Y = 2017
M = 9

dats = (datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 15, 30), datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 16),
        datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 16, 30), datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 17),
        datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 17, 4), datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 17, 30),
        datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 18), datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 18, 30))

issue = {'datetime': dats, 
         '5.0':(2.05, 2.04, 2.04 ,1, float('NaN'), 2.05, 2.04, 5), 
         '6.0':(5.8, 5.9, 5.2, float('NaN'), 6, 6.01, 5, 5.02)}
issue = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(issue)
```

I would like to summarize the data in this dataframe to only contain half-hourly points and take the mean over any values that happen during that half-hour (excluding `nan` values). So the end goal would be to have a dataframe that looks like the `resolution` dataframe created below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

Y = 2017
M = 9

dats2 = (datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 15, 30), datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 16),
         datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 16, 30), datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 17), 
         datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 17, 30), datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 18), 
         datetime.datetime(Y, M, M, 18, 30))

resolution = {'datetime': dats2, 
              '5.0':(2.05, 2.04, 2.04 ,1, 2.05, 2.04, 5), 
              '6.0':(5.8, 5.9, 5.2, 6, 6.01, 5, 5.02)}
resolution = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resolution)
```

I am easily able to do this in R using `dplyr`, but with Python I'm still somewhat of a noob. Thanks in advance for any and all help on the matter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even shorter than in R

```
issue.set_index('datetime').resample('30 min').mean()
Out[685]: 
                      5.0   6.0
datetime                       
2017-09-09 15:30:00  2.05  5.80
2017-09-09 16:00:00  2.04  5.90
2017-09-09 16:30:00  2.04  5.20
2017-09-09 17:00:00  1.00  6.00
2017-09-09 17:30:00  2.05  6.01
2017-09-09 18:00:00  2.04  5.00
2017-09-09 18:30:00  5.00  5.02
```